# Drupal 4.7 Unable to connect to database server

Tags: php, drupal, mysql-connect

This is strange, in Drupal 4.7 (a new install) I can get it to come up with a page that says "Unable to connect to database server" when I have not put in the DB connect information. This comes up in the browser just fine.

So I go in an put in the correct connect info (which works fine with my Drupal 6 sites) and I suddenly get a white screen. If I run cron.php I see the same HTML spit out that created the DB error before this.

Any idea what is going on?

UPDATE: I made a mistake, my webserver is actually using PHP 5.2. This is due to the fact that I am running this on my Macbook Pro which comes with PHP and Apache, but I am using Zend Server CE for my local web dev environment.

Sys info:

- Drupal 4.7.11
- PHP 5.3.4
- MySQL 5.1.54

Any thoughts or ideas are welcome. I am really not sure where to go with this and I need to be able to get Drupal 4 working on my system to do a content migration from some older sites. (Yep, I wasn't using Drupal 4.7 to punish myself. I have a good reason).

Comment: I'd be surprised if Drupal 4.7 is PHP 5.3 compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out awhile ago. Unfortunately I don't remember what I did, but I got it to work at least to the extent that I could bootstrap Drupal and then load the nodes and export them.

I am going to set this as solved. I apologize for not having the answer in here. It may have been LDAP, which comes with XAMPP but not Zend. I know that was a major problem on the Drupal6 version of this site.